# LoadError: MethodError: no method matching getname(::Int64)

Tags: julia

I try to run the following code block:

```
using JuMP
using CPLEX  
function solveRMP(cust::Int64,
  routes::Array{Float64,2},
  routeCost::Array{Float64,1},
  m::Int64)

  cust_dep = cust+2;

  rmp = Model(solver = CplexSolver())
  # Add decistion variables
  @variable(rmp, 0<=x[1:size(routes,2)])
  #
  # Add objective
  @objective(rmp, Min, sum(routeCost[r]*x[r] for r=1:size(routes,2)))
  # #####################
  # ### Constraints
  @constraint(rmp, cVisitCust[i=2:cust_dep-1], sum(routes[i,r]*x[r] for r=1:size(routes,2)) == 1)
  @constraint(rmp, cMaxNrRoutes, sum(x[r] for r=1:size(routes,2)) <= m )

  allConstraints = vcat(cVisitCust,cMaxNrRoutes)


  writeLP(rmp, "myRMP.lp", genericnames=false);


  solve(rmp)
  duals = zeros(1,1)
  append!(duals,getdual(allConstraints))

  return  getvalue(x), duals 
end
```

and I get the following error:

```
**LoadError: MethodError: no method matching getname(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  getname(!Matched::Expr) at 
(...) **
```

Comment: Be helpful to see the full error so we can see in which function it occurred.

Comment: When doing ` <= m` in the last constraint, try to replace `m` with `Float64(m)`. The solver uses continuous values and integers confuse it.

Comment: I tried what you mentioned but the error is still there

Comment: `while loading ...\VRTW.jl, in expression starting on line 28
include_string(::String, ::String) at loading.jl:515
include_string(::Module, ::String, ::String) at Compat.jl:577
(::Atom.##55#58{String,String})() at eval.jl:73
withpath(::Atom.##55#58{String,String}, ::String) at utils.jl:30
withpath(::Function, ::String) at eval.jl:38
macro expansion at eval.jl:71 [inlined]
(::Atom.##54#57{Dict{String,Any}})() at task.jl:80`

Comment: line 28 refers to the one where the function starts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the declaration of the variables `x`,

```
@variable(rmp, 0<=x[1:size(routes,2)])
```

the constraint needs to be on the right side of the variable name

```
@variable(rmp, x[1:size(routes,2)] >= 0)
```

Otherwise `0` is interpreted as a variable name, leading to the error.